# Getting issue with ngModel and REST API call Headers

Tags: angular, rest, authentication

I have developed a simple form where i have to post the data using HTTP Post in angular 4. So for that i am sending the POST request then the server is giving the Status as 200 OK. But i am not getting any response data from the server. I am using the basic authentication.

```
    postInvoiceDetails(invoice: Invoice): Observable<Invoice>{
            let headers = new Headers();
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });        
            this.authorizeHeaders(headers);
            return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl + 'entity/node?_format=hal_json', invoice, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
        }

        private extractData(res: Response) {
            let body = res.json();
                return body.data || {};
        }

        private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) {
            console.error(error.message || error);
            return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
        }

//Basic Authentication with username and password
     authorizeHeaders(headers: Headers){
         console.log('Getting Headers Info.');
        //let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('apiuser:@piUser@2017Supplier'));
        let options = new RequestOptions();
        options.headers = headers;
        console.log(options);
    }
```

When i send the post request then the POST request is showing 200 Ok. See below screen for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Another issue is what i am facing is i am not able to use the ngModel for 2 way databinding. When i use this then it says "RROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nid' of undefined" in the form.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
<app-dialog [(visible)]="showDialog">

    <div style="background-color:#363636; color:#ffffff; padding: 7px;
    margin: -12px -12px 12px -12px;">ADD NEW INVOICE</div>
    <div><label>Request ID *</label><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.nid"></div>
    <div><label>Date *</label>

      <my-date-picker name="mydate" [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
      required></my-date-picker>

    </div>
    <div><label>Category *</label></div>
    <div><label>Details *</label></div>
    <div><label>Job (Optional)*</label></div>
    <div><label>Select Upload</label>
  <p>
    Single: <input type="checkbox" name="uploadtype" value="single" />
    Weekly: <input type="checkbox" checked name="uploadtype" value="weekly" />
    Monthly: <input type="checkbox" name="uploadtype" value="monthly" /><br />
  </p>
    </div>
    <div>Upload Document *: <span>
      <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">

    </span></div>
    <div>Amount *</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>

  <div *ngIf="email" [ngClass] = "'success'"> {{email}} Added. </div>
  <div *ngIf="errorMessage" [ngClass] = "'error'"> {{errorMessage}} </div> 
  </app-dialog>
</div>
  <!--Dialog box markup end -->
```

The above one is the dialog box which is written in another component and i am trying to use the object which i have created in the invoice.component.html. But its not working.

Can anyone help me? The demo is available here with code also. [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tr38tr?file=app%2Fcomponents%2Finvoice%2Finvoice.component.html)

Comment: Well the preflight error means that you are having a CORS issue. Make sure CORS is enabled in the backend.

Comment: Yes CORS issue is resolved as the backend people enabled it. But why the ngModel in the form error comes.

Comment: `item` is initially undefined. You can wrap your code inside a div with `*ngIf="item"`, or just initialize your `item` as an empty object.